# Por qué mi puntero Matriz a null, cancela el mensaje de comprobación de mi destructor de clase.( Aprendo a trabajar con memoria dinámica)

Tags: c++, punteros, destructor

```
int main() {
Empresa* Matriz= new 
Empresa("Clinica del 
Sol",  "Ciudad de Bs 
As");
Matriz ->mostrar();
Matriz= nullptr;
delete Matriz;
return 0;
       }
```

Está bien liberada la memoria así?. Al cancelar la línea Matriz=nullptr el mensaje del destructor se imprime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al hacer:

```
    Empresa* Matriz= new Empresa("Clinica del Sol",  "Ciudad de Bs As");
```

Matriz tendrá guardada la dirección de memoria del objeto. Cuando haces:

```
    Matriz = nullptr;
```

`Matriz` dejara de apuntar al objeto que creaste, y va a puntar a `0`.

Entonces cuando haces:

```
    delete Matriz;
```

Le estas pidiendo borrar el objeto que este en la dirección `0`, no al objeto
que tu creaste originalmente. Por eso es que no te sale la llamada al
destructor.

Creo que lo que tratabas de hacer es seguir el patrón que se usa en C de
liberar y dar el valor de null. Solo que en tu caso lo hiciste al revés.

```
    free(ptr);
    ptr = NULL;
```

**Nota:** Estas en C++, así que no tienes ningún motivo para manejar la memoria
directamente. Lo correcto es que uses `std::unique_ptr`. Si lo haces de esa
manera:

1. No tendrás que llamar manualmente a `delete`.
2. Cuando hagas `ptr = nullptr` se liberara la memoria automáticamente.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu tiempo y tu comentario, me das elementos para investigar. Gracias totales